# For a large set of coordinates, how to fast insert/update/delete/fetch_by_range to this set

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Say I have a large set of coordinates

`all_users = [{:user_id=>1,:x=>100,:y=>100}, {:user_id=>2,:x=>120,:y=>120}, ...]`

And there are several operations here:

- insert

  A player comes online, reporting his current coordinate

  `all_users << {:user_id=>3,:x=>150,:y=>150}`
- update coord by user_id

  A player moves to a new coordinate

  `user = all_users.detect {|u| u[:user_id] == current_user_id }`

  `user.update :x => new_x, :y => new_y if user`
- delete by user_id

  A player logs off

  `all_users.delete_if {|u| u[:user_id] == current_user_id }`
- find by coord range

  Find the user around me, +-100 say.

  `all_users.select {|u| u[:user_id] != current_user_id && (u[:x] - me[:x]).abs <= 100 && (u[:y] - me[:y]).abs <= 100 }`

Though as you can see, the update/delete/find operation are all O(n), and I think I can do better than that, maybe designing external indexes for user_id & x & y is an option, just like what database does. Any other thoughts?

Comment: For the find operation, you might split up your data into 200x200 squares. That way, you will only have to search through the 4 neighboring squares for each find. It's still O(n), but it's a faster O(n).

Comment: Yeah that's better that a simple linear search in an array. But it only works fine when players are spread evenly over the map. Say lots of players are crowded in a small area, then splitting the data won't help much. That brings up another question: should I push exactly all the events(login/move/logoff) to the clients, if not, what or when should I push? The client might have trouble of rendering hundreds of players itself, because this actually is a web game, and the client is flash.Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: If you're actually trying to make a game, then I'd recommend not worrying about any of this until you have a working game. Just send all the data you can, and when things actually start to be slow, then find ways to optimize. If you're just looking for more theoretical ideas, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on a real-deal game. And you're right, at present, I should be more concerned about the core algorithm itself. I already did some test on the sample code above, with nearly 5000 people on a map with 400x400 size, spread evenly, 20-30 guys move per second, the notify range is 20x20, and the cpu usage is about 50%-60% (a single core).

Comment: You should index your users with a `Hash` by `user_id` to start with. Any time you start marching through an `Array` looking for things (`detect`, `delete_if`) you should consider moving to a `Hash` implementation instead. `Hash` lookups will be more like O(1), when your current `detect` method is O(n).

Comment: @Casper, that's exactly what I thought with user_id. But the operation 'find by range' seems a bit trickier :)

Comment: Ok right. You probably won't find the answer to that question on SO. That question is more of a game development / graph theory optimization algorithm thing. As en example look here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/how-do-i-optimize-searching-for-the-nearest-point . You might want to ask your question over there. Good luck :)

Comment: I agree a hash is the way to go over an array, but you'll need a couple to do the lookups like you want. I'd recommend looking into SQLite's ability to have an in-memory DB, and Sequel as an ORM using its datasets. That'd get you going and would be pretty fast. It'd give you the ability to have some relational lookups. You could model those using hashes, but since you're in the development/try-this/that stage, it'd help you get a handle on your ideas and how to structure your data, with the ability to quickly change things.

Answer (score 2):

The first three operations you can be easily solved if you create a hash table with the `user_id` being the key. This will reduce the complexity of the operations to amortized `O(1)`.

The last operation is a bit ambiguous: what should the method return if there is more than one user in the range? Will it be an array of users? Given your sub-optimal solution, I assume you are interested in all users in the range. This can never be improved in worst case, because the answer itself might be all `n` users (thus complexity of `O(n)`).

The act of finding all points within given rectangle is called spatial indexing. One of the most commonly used solutions for such query is the [Quad Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Still, my note for the worst case scenario holds true for sure, whatever structure you choose to use.

As I mentioned in the comment below, you need not worry for the fact I mention two different structures for implementing the different operations. It is very often that you use more than one representation of the same data set in order to get all operations optimal.

Comment: I want all the users within the range. Maybe I can use some other data structure, like a k-d tree. But I'm not sure if it's worth the effort at all because that'll cause everything(including insert/update/delete) to be a O(ln N) operation

Comment: @DeanWinchester: Totally not so. In such cases it is common that you keep the data in two structures in parallel. That way you use twice as much memory,but you can service many operations faster. In your case hash table is the correct choice for one of them. As for the kd-tree: I do not know how to implement it in dynamic way so that to allow insertion of new nodes. You actually need to use the so called quad tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree. I am adding the link also to my answer

Comment: +1 "It is very often that you use more than one representation of the same data set". That's what I'd do. An in-memory SQLite table might work nicely, or one of the no-sql-type solutions. Start with an ORM like Sequel using its datasets to gain easy SQL generation and SQLite in memory for speed, then optimize later.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev, I'll try quadtree later. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @theTinMan, the whole story is: 
1. user reports to the server his own coordinate and receives others. 2. when user moves to a new coordinate, the server updates it, and push the new coordinate to others within a certain range. 
So I'm not comfortable about using an extra storage for those things because of the 'push' stuff.